# Constructing "array" of noncopyable objects

Tags: c++, boost, stl, vector

I have a class that's inhenerently non-copyable (a thread, so there's no copy semantics that make sense), and I want to have a largeish 'array' of these, identically constructed with a non-default constructor. Note that the array is fixed size.

I can only use the default constructor with C++ arrays, unless I initialise each one independently.

```
Thread myArray[128];   // uses default constructor - wrong
```

I can list the object constructors and parameters explicitly, but that's verbose and ugly

```
Thread myArray[128] = { Thread(params,...), Thread(params,...), ... x 128 ;  // ugly
```

It seems I can't use stl vectors because the object is non-copyable - event though the vector never changes size. I guess the constructor actually does copying!

```
std::vector<Thread> myVector(128, Thread(params,...));// won't compile
```

The way I've though of doing this is with an array of smart pointers and an initialization loop, but maybe I'm missing something:

Is there any other way - maybe with boost containers, or a different container type?

Comment: Using a smart-pointer seems like the sensible thing to do. I don't think there is a better way.

Comment: If they are "identically constructed", can you not add a default constructor that does that? Otherwise go with @Space_C0wb0y.

Comment: The Qt library is a quite famous library, and they handle arrays of non copyable objects (the GUI widgets, totally non copyable) with pointers. So I guess that smart pointers are the way to go.

Comment: Even if you can't add a default constructor, you could derive: the derived class could have a default constructor which passes the desired arguments to the `Thread` constructor.  You then create an array of the default class.

Comment: @Bo, @James that's a neat idea. Unfortunately one of the params is a boost::function result, and the default constructor doesn't know which class instance it belongs to.

Comment: Strongly consider a boost::ptr_vector over a vector of smart pointers.

Comment: @Fred. Thanks, but ptr_vector ain't supported by my 1/2 baked compiler :-<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vector of smart pointers, with each instance dynamically
allocated, is definitely the simplest way.  Otherwise (and I'd
only do this if absolutely necessary), you can more or less
emulate what `std::vector` does internally.  Something along the
lines of:

```
union
{
    double just_to_ensure_alignment;
    unsigned char data[ sizeof(Thread) * elementCount ];
} array;

//  construct...
for ( int i = 0; i != elementCount; ++ i )
    new (data + i * sizeof(Thread)) Thread(params,...);

//  access...
Thread& getAt( int i )
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Thread*>( data + i * sizeof(Thread) );
}
```

(I'd actually wrap this in a class, if only to be able to use
`operator[]` instead of `getAt`.)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using an array of boost::shared_ptr

Answer (score 6):

This may seem like totally crazy (and it probably is), but...

```
struct ThreadInitValues{
  // your actual params
  int i;
  float f;
};

struct Thread{
    Thread(int i = _init.i, float f = _init.f)
      : _i(i)
      , _f(f)
    {}

    static ThreadInitValues _init;

private:
    // uncopyable
    Thread(Thread const&);
    Thread& operator=(Thread const& other);

    // your actual member
    int _i;
    float _f;
};

ThreadInitValues Thread::_init;

int main(){
    Thread::_init.i = 5;
    Thread::_init.f = 3.14f;
    Thread arr[128];
}
```

Maybe this works out for you. :) Of course, you now need to watch out if the array is initialized in multithreaded code itself...

Comment: +1 for crazy. But I think the array of smart pointers is more idiomatic, and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

For new compilers supporting r-value references, being copyable is not necessary for vector elements AFAIK. To use it without copying 128 push_back's should be used (creating new object each time), because creting several objects from a single one *is* a copying :).

If this way is not available, try [boost::ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) or std::vector of boost::shared_ptr.

Comment: Beware: MSVC falsly tries to access the copy ctor on copy elision even though it should access the move ctor

Comment: Hmm. But won't the `myVector(128, Thread(params,...))` constructor still need to do copying? After all, I'm only passing in one object and I want 128 created...

Answer (score 0):

I am not that much big programmer. But did you try this

```
std::vector<YourObject *> temp_Vec;
for(int i=0;i<128;++i)
    temp_Vec.push_back(new YourObject(arguments));
```

Comment: Smart pointers would be much safer. boost::scoped_ptr, for example.